# How can I use terraform to setup in multi regions?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform configurations file without modules and it is hosted in production .

Currently I am trying to deploy it in another region using provider alias and modules .But when I plan the same , it says that I need to destroy my previous configuration and recreate it via modules

When I modularise the files are tehy treated by terraform as a new resource ?I have around 35 reources , it says 35 to destroy and 35 to create .In the process of modularising I removed the .terraform folder under the root and initialised it in the main module

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected behaviour because the resources have now different Terraform identifiers. When Terraform runs *plan* or *apply*, it looks in the status file and cannot find the new identifiers listed there.

You can solve this situation using the [terraform state mv](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html) command. I have used it successfully, but it is a tedious task and mistakes are easy. I recommend to make additional backups of your state file via `-backup-out` option and checking the plan after each run.

Comment: Thank you so much @Giulio Vian .I understood this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look into terragrunt to make your code more dry. Once you've integrated with Terragrunt you can start using a hierarchy like this:

```
--root
  terragrunt.hcl
     |
     --dev_account
       account.hcl
       |
       --us-east-2
       region.hcl
         |
         --services
       --us-east-1
       --us-west-2
     --uat_account
       |
       --us-east-2
         |
         --services
       --us-east-1
       --us-west-2
     --prod_account
       |
       --us-east-2
         |
         --services
       --us-east-1
       --us-west-2
```

Terragrunt will allow you to have one module and with a hierarchy similar to this, you'll be able to parse the account.hcl, and region.hcls to deploy to different regions without having to re-enter this information.

Terragrunt allows you to run an apply-all if you choose to apply all child terraform configurations, though I wouldn't suggest this for production.

Comment: I am wondering if terragrunt will help as my terraform tfstate is already in place and with terragrunt not sure if i can let terraform understand that my resources are in place and not to spin it again ,But I really liked this , will read on terragrunt